# What is asset only module and on demand feature of aab(android app bundle) in android?

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

I came to know that aab is better than apk. So I need to know the features of aab, what exactly the meaning of asset only module and on-demand feature.

can anyone please explain this in simple words ??

Answer (score 0):

Per https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle:

> The Android App Bundle is Android's new, official publishing format that offers a more efficient way to build and release your app. The Android App Bundle lets you more easily deliver a great experience in a smaller app size, which can improve install success and reduce uninstalls. It's easy to switch. You don't need to refactor your code to start benefiting from a smaller app. And once you've switched, you'll benefit from modular app development and customizable feature delivery.

All new apps will have to publish App Bundles from August 2021, so if you're building a new app, this is what you should be using.

In simple terms, the App Bundle leaves to Google the hard work of optimizing your app appropriately for each device by sending only the relevant files to each device. For example, a device with an "hdpi" resolution will only receive the "hdpi" resources (this is simplified -- in reality, it's a bit smarter than this, but the whole point is you don't have to worry about it). Same for the localized strings, which often take a big amount of space in the app because they are uncompressed.

All of this makes the app smaller, which has been shown to be correlated with slightly higher number of installs, especially in countries where the connection is weak, or when people are on mobile data. In short, this gets your users sooner engaged in the app.

The App Bundle also allows to have "feature modules" and "asset modules". Modules can be downloaded on the device at a later time in the execution of the app, which helps reduce the app install size even further. Feature modules can contain any kind of files (code, resources, assets, native libraries), while asset modules are one specific type of feature modules that can only contain assets and is mostly useful for game developers. Asset modules are also more decoupled from the app than feature modules (i.e. you can update the app without updating the assets).

Sources:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery
- https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery